# How to disable fields validation if we want to go to the previous step?

Tags: django, validation, django-formwizard

I am using the django's form wizard in the authentication system.
I have 2 form wizards steps. In the second, I have two buttons: the Prev Step button and the Submit button. When the Prev Step button is used to go backwards, I get the django's warning to fill out the field.

How do I disable validations for the Prev Step button and keep the validations for the Submit button?

I already disabled the javascript validations for the Prev Step button.

My html:

```
<!-- Forms -->
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% for field in wizard.form %}
  <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20">
    {{ field }}
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Buttons -->
{% if wizard.steps.next %}
  <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <button type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.next }}" class="login100-form-btn">Next step</button>
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="split-left">
      <button type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}" class="login100-form-btn" formnovalidate>Prev step</button>
    </div>
    <div class="split-right">
        <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

views:

```
class signup(SessionWizardView):
    template_name='accounts/signup.html'
    form_list = [UserCreationForm_1, UserCreationForm_2]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        form_step = [form for form in form_list]

        # step 1: ModelForm
        user = form_step[0].save()
        auth_login( self.request, user )
        # step 2: Form
        user = form_step[1].save()

        return redirect( 'home' )
```

forms:

```
class UserCreationForm_1(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('shown_name', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'shown_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'User name'}),
        }

class UserCreationForm_2(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(  max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'Name'}) )
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField( widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'Date of Birth'}) )
    phone = PhoneNumberField( widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input100', 'placeholder': 'Phone'}) )
```

In the second form wizard step, when I use the Prev button, this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnDHt.jpg

When I use the Submit button, this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrEml.jpg

Comment: your previous button should not be `type="submit"`. Maybe `type="button"` is better, you don't want to submit the current form, but go back.

Comment: I followed the django docs about the form wizard. They use type="submit". It works correctly if I fill all fields, but I want to be able to go backwards with empty / invalid fields.

Comment: because a submit will submit the form and then do a form validation. If you really want to keep the submit there you will need to check in your view if the user press prev or next and if it is prev and prevent the form from trying to validate the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with Django. It was a javascript problem. I only had to remove the class validate-input from the forms' div.